# How to set up a ColdFusion MySQL datasource over SSL?

Tags: mysql, ssl, coldfusion

Is there a way to set up a ColdFusion data source to connect to a MySQL server over a secure connection using SSL?

I don't see any obvious option to enable a SSL connection on the data source in CF administrator.

The only option I can think of is to use the "connection string" field.

This is for a current configuration that is set up. We have other options, but I am curious as to if this is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use the "other" option in the Drivers dropdown and build your own connection string. Here's an article I found on SSL for MySQL through JDBC drivers: http://www.razorsql.com/articles/mysql_ssl_jdbc.html

UPDATE: Here is another article with information on connecting via SSL and updating the keystore with certificate data. There is also some good content in the comments of the page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

Comment: This seemed to work though I did get an error stating "SSL Connection required, but not supported by server." Most likely a MySQL config/install problem.

Comment: JDBC URL: jdbc:mysql://<server>:3306/<dbname>?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true

Comment: DRIVER CLASS: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Unfortunately you've hit the limit of my knowledge. I know that's *the way* to do it, but the ins and outs of the communication to MySQL are beyond my current boundaries. Unfortunately the Google results are *incredibly* slim on this one... http://www.google.com/search?q=%22SSL+Connection+required,+but+not+supported+by+server%22&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&hs=6an&filter=0

Comment: Yeah, I think the original server config requested by the client is going out the window for possible performance issues. So all this will probably just be FYI as opposed to an actual implementation. Thanks for the info though!